# Checkboxes in ExpandaleListView

Tags: android

I am working with expandablelistview with checkboxes as header and child data.when a user expand a group and checked group header then i want to checked all the child check box as well. i try a number of solution but never to gain.
    please help me thanks in advance.

```
**my code is like this**

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
            private Context _context;
            private List<String> _listDataHeader; 
            private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listChildData;

            private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;
            private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
            private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

            public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                    HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
                this._context = context;
                this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
                this._listChildData = listChildData;
                mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();
            }


            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
                return this._listChildData.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                        .get(childPosititon);
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
                final int mChildPosition = childPosition;

                final String childText = (String) getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem, null);

                    childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

                    childViewHolder.mChildText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);

                    childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childcheck);

                    convertView.setTag(R.layout.childitem, childViewHolder);

                }else {

                    childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.childitem);
                }

                childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);

                childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

                if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {

                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);

                    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

                } else {
                    boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];
                    mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                }

                childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                            getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

                        } else {

                            boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                            getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                        }
                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return this._listChildData.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                        .size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return this._listDataHeader.size();
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView( final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.groupitem, null);

                    groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
                    groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtview1);
                    convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
                }
                else {
                    groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(headerTitle);

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public final class GroupViewHolder {
            TextView mGroupText;
            CheckBox mGroupCheckbox;
        }

        public final class ChildViewHolder {

            TextView mChildText;
            CheckBox mCheckBox;
        }

        public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            private final Context context;
            private final String[] values;
            public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
                super(context, R.layout.list, values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listdata);
                textView.setText(values[position]);
                return rowView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no event handler on mGroupCheckbox. You need to handle its check event and cascade down to children

Comment: actually i m new to android... so can you provide me some example or code to solve this..